# Active Choices plugin - not found referenced parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to use Active Choices plugin to get branch list by repo using github api, but it gives me an error that there is no repo - which is a referenced parameter, which is already defined.

In case, I'm using Ubuntu 16.0.4, Jenkins 2.32.2 and Active choices plugin 1.5.3.

```
if (REPO.equals("REPOA")){
    def proc = "curl https://api.github.com/repos/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin/branches | jq -r '[.[] | .name ]'".execute()
    return proc.text
}
else if (REPO.equals("REPOB")){
    def proc = "curl https://api.github.com/repos/jenkinsci/active-choices-plugin/branches | jq -r '[.[] | .name ]' ".execute()
    return proc.text
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

(I also tried to use buffer/stream way since I found some answers about not using 'text' from stackoverflow, but same result. the code part to get branch name is working fine on scriptler edit mode.)

```
def proc ="curl...."
def outputStream = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, System.err)
return outputStream.toString())
```

[referenced parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EY224.png)
[reactive part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9XZ4.png)

The error is as follow:

```
Fallback to default script...
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: REPO for class:  Script1
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot comment to your post for further clarification, so I have to make this an answer. Did you fill out the `Referenced parameters` from the Active Choices Reactive Parameter?

After setting up the initial Active Choice Parameter, you have to reference it in the Active Choices Reactive Parameter (just bellow Choice Type) by filling out the name of the initial Active Choice Parameter. I didn't see the that in your print screens.

Let me know. I hope this helps.

Update:
Nevermind. I'll answer myself. I just saw that you did reference it. My bad. Also saw you bug report from Jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Active-Choices-plugin-not-found-referenced-parameter-td4890493.html

Like Ioannis Moutsatsos-2 said, you should try to just return a list or map from the groovy script instead of text as you are trying right now.

Comment: You should add the actual answer by editing, not as a comment. Welcome to SO, by the way :)

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip :)